# over-exposed window in reflection

Tags: lighting, hdri

I am trying to over-expose the window in this scene:

[image]

But I also want the other reflections on the shower glass to be brighter without affecting the lighting in the room. How do I achieve this? The window is a reflection on the shower glass.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase reflectivity of the glass material. It would probably be possible to make the lighting more visible in reflections with material nodes of the light source using Light Path node's Is Glossy Ray output, but that would effect all materials that have glossy component, so that's not a good solution. You need only to effect the glass so that's what you should do. You can use Add Shader or Mix Shader and Fresnel nodes to simply add a bright glossy shader to whatever material you use for the glass with very little or no roughness at all.  It will reflect all environment more.

I think one of the best ways would be if you do compositing for your renders. You could use Cryptomatte to isolate the glass and then increase the brightness of the glossy component only in reflections that are stronger. Sort of editing the reflections with curves or math and separating the window reflection by strength/brightness, because it is already brighter than most other reflections.

Comment: I have tried it